# How would one carry out principal component analysis in the Beltrami-Klein model of hyperbolic space?

Tags: pca, geometry

This is a follow up to a comment by @whuber in response to this question: [Is there an extension of PCA for data embedded in hyperbolic spaces?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/343014/is-there-an-extension-of-pca-for-data-embedded-in-hyperbolic-spaces)

Sorry, I would have posted it there as a comment but it required 50 reputation points.

What property of the Beltrami-Klein model makes it more suitable for PCA than any of the other models of hyperbolic geometry?